# EF core join Json column with parent table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, json.net, visual-studio-2019

I have table like this

[image]

I want to join these 2 tables in EF Core and I need to get a result like this:

[image]

I tried this code but it is not working:

```
var list = (from s in this.dbcontext.Students
                    join sj in this.dbcontext.Subjects 
                                   where JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(s.SubjectJson).AsEnumerable().Contains(a.SubjectId)
                                    select new 
                                   {
                                       StudentName = s.Name,
                                       Subject = string.Join(",", sj.Subject)
                                         
                                   }).ToList();;

 public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string subjectJson { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; } 
}
```

Error :

```
  .Where(ti => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(subjectJson )
    .Contains(SubjectId))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
```

Translation of method 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Can you please give some more detail about dbcontext ?

Comment: added class details above

Comment: Ok... you have to more verbose when you ask question. Like as there is ctx so definitely it has dbcontext and also your code sample required minimum code that help to reproduce the issue. You simply mention that it is not working.. it is less helpful like what error you get or any other issue.

Comment: @dotnetstep If I understand correctly, he wants to get some working code to a serviceable degree, sir.

Comment: @snr user did not mention that what is not working. Definitely as it try to introduce some json conversion so clientside evaluation required but error details give more insight for community and try to address that issue.

Comment: @dotnetstep i have updated code and error msg.